# Is there a way to get the current active page from a PDF & PPT viewer embeded in a website

Tags: javascript, pdf, plugins, powerpoint

I have a PDF (or PPT) document that i want to embed in a website. This would be done using one of the standard plugins available for this. What I want is to get the current active page number from the plugin in the website.

IE. Using javascript, or anything else, use a function that gets the current active page from the plugin. Does anyone know of either:

a) A specific plugin that would allow this.
b) A workaround, or hack to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. The adobe plugin runs in a completely different sandbox and interacts with the browser through a different API.

You could use imagemagick's command "convert" to turn your pdf into image files, displaying them in the browser via JS. You could create a image slideshow where you know which page your visitor is viewing.